# Видимость страницы как Googlebot

Tags: индексация

Так должен видеть страницу сайта Googlebot или так же, как пользователь?

http://joxi.ru/krDjD8Ru0ly002

Открыл для индексации только главную страницу сайта.

Или нужно ещё открыть для индексации css, javascript файлы? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как настроить..

Comment: Должен видеть как пользователь, css-js открыть крайне желательно

Comment: ок, спасибо. Открыл таким образом http://joxi.ru/EA4Xv94hDBknGA . Это правильно ж?